# Clang : Depends: clang-3.8 (>= 3.8~) but it is not going to be installed

Tags: 20.04, cross-compilation, clang

04, I tried installing clang using the following command

```
`sudo apt install clang`
```

however getting the following error

```
Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
    requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
    distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
    or been moved out of Incoming.
    The following information may help to resolve the situation:
    
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     clang : Depends: clang-3.8 (>= 3.8~) but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: 1. Did you add any external PPA for clang? 2. Retry after running  `sudo apt update`

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I am still getting the same error

Comment: According to https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/clang, in Ubuntu 20.04, it is supposed to install clang-10. Did you somehow install any PPA for clang? An workaround would be to run `sudo apt install clang-10`

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi No, I did not install any PPA for clang, I am new to development and learning, please guide me through this. I tried looking for clang-10 at launchpad however there is only upto 3.6 version. Thank you

Comment: Did you run the command I posted to install clang-10?

Comment: Hi @ArchismanPanigrahi , I did that but I am getting the following error  `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package clang-10
`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)